# Is the use of 'diagonal' correct in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Consider this expression

> This gift is from the guy who sits **diagonal** to me.

Is using **diagonal** correct here or should I use something else?

Comment: If you really want to be idiomatic about it, you could say "this gift is from the guy who sits kitty-corner to me."

Answer (score 5):

It would be more usual to say *diagonally opposite*.

Comment: +1. Also "This gift is the guy who is **diagonally across** from me".

Comment: @thor: If I were in a classroom setting, I might be inclined to say "diagonally across" if the individual where next to me and up one row. I would be more inclined to say "diagonally opposite" if I was sitting in one corner of the room and the subject was in the opposite corner. I don't really have a good sense of where the dividing line between the two choices would be.

Answer (score 2):

*Diagonal* is an adjective or a noun; it is not used as adverb. You should use *diagonally*, as in the following sentence:

> The gift is from the guy who sits **diagonally opposite** me.